# Rendering fields in Play Framework 2 Form when editing existing object

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, crud, playframework-2.1

This may seem a pretty basic question. I'm using Play Framework 2.1.5 with Scala 2.10 to develop a CRUD app (it will have more in the future). I'm also using Twitter Bootstrap 3.2.0. I'm not able to get my template to render the values for a form when I am attempting to update an object.

I'm following along the book [Play for Scala](http://www.manning.com/hilton/). I can already create a new object. Now I want to be able to edit the object.

The `Product` domain object is mapped using [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/):

```
case class Product(ean: Long, name: String, description: String) extends KeyedEntity[Long]
```

The companion `Person` object has the appropriate CRUD functionality. `Product.findByEan(ean)` is a simple search by field query that returns an `Option[Person]`.

The `Persons` controller has the `Form[Person]` mapping:

```
private val productForm = Form(mapping(
    "ean" -> longNumber.verifying("validation.ean.duplicate", Product.findByEan(_).isEmpty),
    "name" -> nonEmptyText,
    "description" -> nonEmptyText)(Product.apply)(Product.unapply))
```

In my `routes`

```
GET        /products                         controllers.Products.list
POST       /products                         controllers.Products.save
GET        /products/new                     controllers.Products.newProduct
GET        /products/$ean<\d{13}>            controllers.Products.show(ean: Long)
GET        /products/$ean<\d{13}>/edit       controllers.Products.edit(ean: Long)
```

The `Products.edit` route ought to load the Product using its `ean` field and prefill out the edit form with the found product.

```
def edit(ean: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
    Product.findByEan(ean) match {
        case Some(product) =>
            Logger.info("found product: ean = " + ean)
            val form = productForm.fill(product)
            Logger.info(form.toString)
            Ok(views.html.products.editProduct(form))
        case None => Redirect(routes.Products.list)
    }
}
```

I know for a fact that I'm successfully retrieving the object as the `Logger` messages clearly show this in the play console.

The `editProducts` template to render the form is:

```
@(productForm: Form[Product])(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@productsLayout(Messages("products.form")) {
    <h2>@Messages("products.form")</h2>

    @helper.form(action = routes.Products.save()) {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                @Messages("products.details", Messages("products.edit"))
            </legend>
            @helper.inputText(productForm("product.ean"))
            @helper.inputText(productForm("product.name"))
            @helper.textarea(productForm("product.description"))
        </fieldset>
        <p><input type="submit" class="btn primary" value='@Messages("products.edit.submit")'</p>
   }
}
```

The problem is that that when I attempt to edit my Product object, this form template is not pre-filling out the `<input>` tag with the `value` attribute from the retrieved product object. The same template works just fine when I try to create an object but submit a form with validation errors.

1. Has anyone else experienced this issue?
2. Does the [twitterBootstrap helper](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.5/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.twitterBootstrap.package) assume Bootstrap 2 rather than Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ad. 1**

Your problem is linked with the way you refer to field names of a form. You shouldn't put a mapping object name as a prefix.

```
@helper.inputText(productForm("ean"))
@helper.inputText(productForm("name"))
@helper.textarea(productForm("description"))
```

**More information**

It's worth to remember that access to a form field is done by providing a name specified in the mapping. The specified field name doesn't have to match a corresponding case class filed name. If your mapping looked like this

```
private val productForm = Form(mapping(
    "id" -> longNumber.verifying("validation.ean.duplicate", Product.findByEan(_).isEmpty),
    "full-name" -> nonEmptyText,
    "desc" -> nonEmptyText)(Product.apply)(Product.unapply))
```

you would access it's fields in a template this way

```
@helper.inputText(productForm("id"))
@helper.inputText(productForm("full-name"))
@helper.textarea(productForm("desc"))
```

**Ad. 2**

Although the field helper works fine if you click on **Twitter Bootstrap** link in the **Twitter bootstrap field constructor** section you will be redirected to the Bootstrap v2.3.2 home page so I guess this helper was designed for the previous version.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaFormHelpers

Besides I suggest reading a Bootstrap section in the **Play 2.3 Migration Guide** which explains why build-in support for Bootstrap is being dropped. You ought to consider creation your custom field helpers for the latest Bootstrap version. It'll alleviate your pain if you ever consider migration to newer version of Play framework.

http://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23

Comment: Thanks. With respect to the field, what a mistake to use the wrong fields. I'm definitely creating my own field helper, as it does make good design sense to eliminate the Twitter Bootstrap helper from the Play framework.